# Find Reflection of A point with respect to a line mirror in 3D

Tags: coordinate-systems, 3d, alternative-proof, reflection, mirror-symmetry

I need to find the reflection of point $P(1,2,3)$  w.r.t line mirror $(x-1)/2 =(y-1)/3 = (z+1)/1$

I know one method to do it i.e by first finding the foot of perpendicular of P on the line by using direction ratios and solving with line and then when the coordinates of foot of perpendicular are known ,I can simply use mid point formula to get the coordinates of reqd reflection point.

I want to know is there any other /alternative method to solve this question ,that'll help me alot.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: midpoint is the fastest method. other way would be to assume a point, find distance to the line, equate and solve couple of equations. More tedious.

Comment: Yes that'll be tediuos.moreover that'll be a single equation for 3 variables isn't it??

Comment: you will get two equations - one equation based on distance between end points (which is double of perp distance) and the other between midpoint and reflection point.

Comment: and you also have to use the equation of the plane they reside in for the third equation

Comment: Ok yes , I get it!thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point on the given line it's $C(1+2t,1+3t,-1+t)$ and the needed point it's $B(1+4t,6t,-5+2t),$ where $C$ is a midpoint of $PB$.

Thus, $$(2t,3t-1,-4+t)(2,3,1)=0,$$ which gives $$4t+9t-3-4+t=0$$ or  $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and we got that $B(3,3,-4).$

Actually. We did not find coordinates of the foot, but coordinates of $C$, which one step less, than in your solution.

Comment: Can u explain a bit how did u get the "needed point $(1+4t,6t,-5+2t)$"

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is the method I already knew(as stated in question).. I wanted to know is there any other method for solving this ques?

Comment: @Ashu tosh  Because $C$ is a midpoint of $PB$: $\frac{1+1+4t}{2}=1+2t$ and the rest is similar.  I don't agree with your last statement. I did not find a foot of the perpendicular.

Comment: The mid point  $C$ you have mentioned is the foot of perpendicular of $P$ on the line ,isn't it?

Comment: @Ashu tosh  But I did not find coordinates of  this foot. It takes one step less.

Comment: But isn't that the same thing? Eventually you have used same steps as my method ,just the order is different. That doesn't make yours a different method.. By different method I refer to a different approach for solving this problem and not to just shuffle the order of steps

Comment: @Ashu tosh  I really don't agree with you! It's not changing of the same steps, but  one step less. Id est, my solution is simpler than your. Also, I don't think that there is really another way because in any case we need to use that the given line is a perpendicular bisector of $PB$, which you and me made.

Comment: Yes your method has 1 step less but that doesn't make it a different method as that's just because I (in my method) did a numerical calculation that wasn't really required.But Still ,your approach is same so method is also eventually same..And Yes I also agree with your point that this might be the only method to solve this question.

Comment: @Ashu tosh OK. I understood this point. If you think that I did not help you, I am ready to delete my post.

Comment: No no,I appreciate your answer and let it be here..I'll just wait if someone does it with a different approach otherwise I'll term yours as the correct answer (concluding that this is the only method to answer this question)

Comment: @Math Lover  It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: $(3,3,-4)$ is correct answer